# Compatiblity of Material Design to versions below Android 5.0?

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to use material design themes for versions below Android 5.0?
According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html), it is not the case:

> Material design is a comprehensive guide for visual, motion, and
>   interaction design across platforms and devices. Android now includes
>   support for material design apps. To use material design in your
>   Android apps, follow the guidelines defined in the material design
>   specification and use the new components and functionality available
>   in Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above.

Comment: yes its possible use Theme's derived from Theme.AppCompat from the backward compatibility library

Comment: The other answers answer should answer your question, but I would also like to point a useful library to add in lolliop widgets into pre-lollipop devices: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: use this library for Buttons and Animations-  http://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary and for navigation drawer https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar

Answer (score 2):

You can use the support library to have some of features in older versions as well as mentioned in below link:-

https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

also as mentioned below you can visit this link as well:-

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppCompat as stated here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Everything you are asking for is in that link. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use material design themes below android 5.0. U can follow this link to see backward compatibility [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

and to learn more about material design use this 
[link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompat lib as stated in other comments and
One of the best examples of using material compatibility is.

https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar