# Material designing not supporting in android 4 and below versions

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying build my application Android version 4 and below versions but my application not showing UI designing in below 4 version mobiles

Above 4 version mobiles designing is showing and remaining also working fine can some one help me please.

And i am getting to may crashes once open application which are related to material designing items below 4 version mobiles

### Gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karvyclick.fos"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode true
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: check the docs https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: those docs showing material desihggninh support only 5.0 and api level 21

Comment: Nilu may i know material design support below versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243850/compatiblity-of-material-design-to-versions-below-android-5-0

Comment: those are saying material design support only above 5 and api level 21,What is your opinion?

Comment: read this comment of raghunandan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243850/compatiblity-of-material-design-to-versions-below-android-5-0#comment42963238_27243850

Answer (score 0):

Just add `name` under `application` tag in manifest as `MultiDexApplication`

```
<application
        ....
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        ...
</application>
```

**EDIT**

In your case, just add below code snippet in your existing Application Tag

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Comment: i have one Application class there i have installed so many libraries if i use this then what about my Application class?

Comment: I am fully confussed why it's not supporting 4 and below 4 mobile versions

Comment: Do you have idea about this?